# Join of two files

Tags: shell, join

I have two files and i am performing join operation as follows:

```
  nmmadaan@nmmadaan] cat one.txt                                                                                                                                                                     ~
    a b
    e f
    c k
    nmmadaan@nmmadaan] cat two.txt                                                                                                                                                                     ~
    a h
    c j
    e p
    nmmadaan@nmmadaan] join one.txt two.txt                                                                                                                                                            ~
    a b h
    e f p
    nmmadaan@nmmadaan] join two.txt one.txt                                                                                                                                                            ~
    a h b
    e p f
```

Why join two.txt one.txt doesnt give the row with first column as 'c' . Why both joins considering the row with 'e' in first column?

Comment: Input should be sorted

Answer (score 5):

Please read the manual page - http://linux.die.net/man/1/join The files need to be sorted on the join field

i.e. one.txt is not sorted on the join field.

Comment: The link is fine. There was just a typo.Why downvote? The answer is correct.

Comment: @snyder - Works perfectly for me

Comment: Despite that I don't think it was enough to vote negative on it whoever did. And +1 for I think this is the one that gives the general idea for the answer to the question.

Comment: @snyder: Seems that some of our members are very trigger-happy participants of the rat race...

Comment: @konsolebox - Thanks - We all make typos from time to time and usually they are easy to spot

Comment: @konsolebox, CostisAivalis My mistake, will keep in mind next time and for the record, I didn't downvoted the answer infact I never downvoted any answer till now. As a proof here is 3rd vote from my side.

Comment: @snyder - Manners must prevail - you got a +1

Comment: @snyder: No problem! The comment was for the downvoter he/she/it knows! :-)

Comment: @CostisAivalis - What is an "it"? Even my dog has a gender and is happy to show to all his gender - too often IMHO?

Answer (score 3):

Try saying:

```
$ join <(sort one.txt) <(sort two.txt)
a b h
c k j
e f p
```